# Несколько выстрелов.Java апплет

Tags: applet, java

У меня есть программа , стреляющая пушка, подкажите как сделать чтобы при нажатий кнопки, пушка стреляла не 1 раз ?

```
    package gun;

import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Gun extends Applet implements Runnable {

    static final String Set = "Pow";
    int x0 = 275, y0 = 390, k = 1, v0 = 85, x, y;
    double time = 0, alfa0, alfa;
    Button btn;
    Color col, col1, col2, col3, col4;
    Image img, img2;
    Font font;
    Thread t;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        btn = new Button(Set);
        add("North", btn);
        font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 48);

        col = new Color(69, 139, 0);
        col1 = new Color(139, 71, 38);
        col2 = new Color(71, 60, 139);
        col3 = new Color(0, 139, 0);
        col4 = new Color(65, 66, 71);
        img = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "1.png");
        img2 = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "2.png");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {

            time += 0.1;
            alfa0 = 45;
            alfa = alfa0 * 3.14 / 180;
            x = (int) (x0 + v0 * time * Math.cos(alfa));
            y = (int) (y0 - v0 * time * Math.sin(alfa) + 9.8 * (Math.pow(time, 2)) / 2);

            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Gun.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        if ((x > 1000) && (x < 1230) && (y > 380) && (y < 620)) {

            g.drawImage(img2, 20, 378, this);
        }
        g.drawImage(img2, 20, 378, this);
        //cvet fona
        setBackground(new Color(238, 232, 170));
        //zemlya i cel'
        g.setColor(col);
        g.fillRect(0, 500, 2000, 800);
        g.drawImage(img, 1000, 380, this);

        g.setColor(col1);
        g.fillRect(1200, 250, 35, 250);
        g.setColor(col3);
        g.fillOval(1155, 200, 130, 150);

        g.setColor(col2);
        int[] X = {40, 220, 230, 50, 40};
        int[] Y = {430, 390, 430, 460, 430};
        g.fillPolygon(X, Y, X.length);
        //bolwoi krug
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.fillOval(60, 420, 80, 80);
        //srednii
        g.setColor(col1);
        g.fillOval(70, 430, 60, 60);
        //malenkii
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.fillOval(90, 450, 20, 20);
        //polosi
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.drawLine(58, 458, 138, 458);
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.drawLine(59, 459, 139, 459);
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.drawLine(60, 460, 140, 460);
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.drawLine(59, 461, 139, 461);
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.drawLine(58, 462, 138, 462);
        //verticalnie polosi
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.drawLine(99, 419, 99, 499);
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.drawLine(100, 420, 100, 500);
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.drawLine(101, 419, 101, 501);
        //iskra
        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        int[] X1 = {220, 240, 225, 233, 228, 240, 231, 238, 230, 242, 230};
        int[] Y1 = {390, 380, 393, 395, 400, 402, 407, 415, 417, 431, 430};
        g.fillPolygon(X1, Y1, X1.length);
        //yadra
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(150, 470, 30, 30);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(185, 470, 30, 30);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(168, 447, 30, 30);

        g.setColor(col4);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 15, 15);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleEvent(Event evt) {

        switch (evt.id) {
            case Event.ACTION_EVENT: {
                if ((evt.arg == Set) && (k == 2)) {
                    k = 1;
                } else if ((evt.arg == Set) && (k == 1)) {
                    k = 2;
                    t = new Thread(this);
                    t.start();
                    repaint();
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Запустите 2 треда, причем каждый со своим набором координат `x, y`

Comment: @Barmaley ♦ это будет 2 выстрела ?

Comment: Выстрел у вас запускается как: `new Thread(this).start()`, если запустите 2 таких треда - это будет 2 выстрела, правда в текущей компоновке это все равно не будет работать, поскольку координаты снарядов `x, y` для выстрелов одинаковы... так что полюбас придется переписывать и причем довольно серьезно.